# async.waterfall randomly sorts results

Tags: node.js, async.js

I was writing a nest code, tried using async.waterfall or async.series but I am getting random results every time I refresh. it seems to be because of the queries of the first 2 functions randomly finishing.

first query was sorting to committed_date DESC. but when I add the 2 sub queries. the sort gets distorted.

Step1: Loop landingpages
    Step1.1 - fetch details1 repositories
    Step1.2 - fetch details2 versions
Step2: build array

```
db.collection('landingpages').find({is_deleted:{$ne:1}}).sort({committed_date:-1}).limit(10).toArray(function(err, db_results) { 
    var data_array = [];
    var x=1;

    if(db_results.length == 0) { 
        return_data.lps = data_array;
            parallel_done();
    }else{

        async.each(db_results, function (db_results1, cb) {

            async.watefall(
                [
                    function(callback) {
                        //if this is removed or passed as callback(null, ""); the sort is fixed from committed - 1
                        var data_repo = {};

                        db.collection('repositories').find({repository_id: repository_id}).toArray(function(err, db_results1) { 

                            if(db_results1.length == 0){
                                var data_repo = {};
                                callback(null, data_repo);
                            }else{
                                var data_repo = db_results1[0];
                                callback(null, data_repo);
                            }
                        });
                    },
                    function(callback) {
                        //if this is removed or passed as callback(null, ""); the sort is fixed from committed - 1
                        var data_version = {};

                        db.collection('versions').find({landingpage_id: landingpage_id}).sort({_id:-1}).limit(1).toArray(function(err, db_results1) { 
                            if(db_results1.length == 0){
                                var data_version = {};
                                callback(null, data_version);
                            }else{
                                var data_version = db_results1[0];
                                callback(null, data_version);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                ],
                function (err, data_repo,data_version) {

                    var document = {
                        "x": x++,   
                        "landingpage_id": db_results1.landingpage_id,
                        "repository_id": db_results1.repository_id,
                        "version_id": data_version.version_id,
                        "val": db_results1,
                        "data_repo": data_repo,
                        "data_version": data_version,
                    };

                    data_array.push(document);

                    if(data_array.length == db_results.length) { 
                        return_data.lps = data_array;
                    }
                }
            );
        });
    }

});
```

Comment: I suggest you implementing promises (and if you can async/await), it will be more readable and easier to debug

Comment: Any sample you can show with similar logic?

Comment: I converted half of your code using async/await. Tell me it doenst look better: https://gist.github.com/SunriseM/b818c4e7ab8e56570774cef8a1ba82d2

Comment: looks cleaner alright, looks like php coding (which I am used to) blocking.

Comment: im always getting SyntaxError: Unexpected token function

Comment: you need to use Node version > 7.6 to use async/await

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162385/discussion-between-boy-and-sunrisem).

Comment: still getting random sort, but if I remove the 2 sub queries. getting the correct results like how waterfall/series is.